# Adding more sound files to resource packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

If I create a resource pack for Minecraft, am I able to have more natural sounds than there already are? For example, creeper sound files range from "creeper1" to "creeper4". If I were to add a file named "creeper5" will it play naturally, at random, just like all the other "creeper#" files? Or are only a certain range of files set to play?

Also, if I add a sound file that wouldn't overwrite sounds files that already exist (such as someone narrating an intro, named "intro.ogg"), would I be able to play that sound in a command block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are able to play **custom sounds** with Command Blocks using command:

```
playsound <sound> <player> [x] [y] [z] [Volume] [Pitch] [minimumVolume]
```

[Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) has the following description:

> Example: Sound located at `.minecraft\assets\sound\mob\pig\death.ogg`
> The value for **sound** would be written as `mob.pig.death`, as the
> command originates from the sound folder. For sequentially numbered
> files pertaining to the same event (like various walking sounds), the
> player must exclude the number of the sound (for example, sound
> located at `.minecraft\assets\sound\mob\pig\say2.ogg`). In this case,
> the command will play a randomly selected sound out of the three
> available. A player or area must be selected, and the player must be
> able to hear the sound from where it is played.

I have no knowledge on adding more **numbered sounds**, but the wording of the above description makes me think it should be handled OK by the game. Unless anyone else adds that information, you'll have to test yourself - just add a loud scream to zombie groans and walk around for some time :)